# Relacionar dois DataFrames no pandas e retornar valor no python

Tags: python, pandas, ipython-notebook

Tenho dois Dataframes, ambos em csv que import no pandas, um com o historico de registros de protocolos e um com uma lista de pessoaos autorizadas a fazer alterações nos registros de procotolos.

Como eu posso fazer um novo dataframe onde eu verifique se quem fez a alteração no registro de protocolo está na lista de pessoas autorizadas? Além disso que retorne um valor de 'Autorizado' 'Não autorizado'?

Estou utilizando o jupyter notebook

As unicas colunas em comum é a de login, mas elas tem nomes diferentes. A coluna de login na tabela de historico é a coluna CUSUAR_INCL_REG.

Dados de histórico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dados de acesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Diante disso, queria retornar uma nova coluna na tabela de histórico com o retorno: 'Está na lista de acesso' ou 'não está na lista de acesso'.

Comment: Você poderia, por favor, colocar um trecho dos conjuntos de dados para que nós possamos entender melhor o problema?

Comment: Oi @joão, inseri na pergunta. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Caro,

Fiquei em dúvida com sua colocação abaixo.

> As unicas colunas em comum é a de login, mas elas tem nomes diferentes. A coluna de login na tabela de historico é a coluna CUSUAR_INCL_REG.

Porém nas tabelas que você apresentou, até os dados são diferentes.

Imaginando que há dados iguais nas referidas colunas, você pode usar o `merge`

```
novo_dataframe = pd.merge(dfhistorico, dfacesso, left_on=['CUSUAR_INCL_REG'], right_on=['LOGIN'])
```

Dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), pois o `merge` possui vários parâmetros.

Espero que ajude